# How do I split the list of one index into individual elements?

Tags: python, list, csv

```
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    column_name = next(reader)
    print(column_name)
    print(len(column_name)
```

output:['fixed acidity;"volatile acidity";"citric acid";"residual sugar";"chlorides";"free sulfur dioxide";"total sulfur dioxide";"density";"pH";"sulphates";"alcohol";"quality"']
output: 1

How do I split the list into individual elements?

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  I *think* that the problem is simply that you need to work through a tutorial on how to iterate through a list.  It's hard to tell, since you haven't clearly specified the problem, and the "output" you list is not something that Python would produce.

Answer (score 1):

**CSV** stands for [***C***omma **S**eparated **V**alues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). So by default, it is assumed that the fields are delimited by a comma (`,`).

Here, your delimiter seems to be a colon (`;`).

You need to override the default delimiter with the one you're using :

```py
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    # ...
```

See also [the `csv` Python module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader).